# How to paint on a Jpanel I've made?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, paint, paintcomponent

I'm trying to use paintComponent or paint to display shapes on a JPanel I've added to my frame. I've tried many tutorials but they seem to just make the whole frame a "panel". I want to add to my JPanel that I've added to my frame.

Here is my code so far:

```java
public class SelectGeometricFigures extends JPanel {
    
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        g.fillOval(0, 0, 60, 60);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
             SelectGeometricFigures g = new SelectGeometricFigures();
             JFrame f = new JFrame("Select Shapes");
             f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
             f.setLayout(null);
             
             JPanel drawingPanel = new JPanel();
             
             drawingPanel.setBounds(50, 0, 300, 200);
             
             Border blackline = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black);
             drawingPanel.setBorder(blackline);
             
             
             // add to frame
             f.add(drawingPanel);
             f.setSize(500, 500);
             f.setVisible(true);
    }
```

I don't want to make the frame one giant panel and draw on it as I'm adding radio buttons to create specific shapes, which I'm only seeing people online showing you how to extend the JPanel for the whole frame. Is what I'm asking not possible?

Comment: I don't get the problem. You want do add `g` to `drawingPanel`? Just do it. But note, that JPanel uses a `FlowLayout` bei default, a layout manager which lays out components at their preferred size. As your class doesn't override `getPreferredSize` nor is the preferred size set on `g`, you probably won't see anything. Please read [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)

Comment: Nothing shows up when i run it & it has no idea who g is because its in a different method. & there is no getPrefferedSize method available for g.

Comment: Oh, I'm not talking about Graphics g, but about `SelectGeometricFigures g` :-)

Comment: null layout is __wrong__ .. __always__

Comment: [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) lesson in trail _Creating a GUI With Swing_ which is part of Oracle's Java tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;

public class SelectGeometricFigures extends JPanel {
    
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        g.fillOval(0, 0, 60, 60);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Let's create a panel with buttons.
        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel(); // FlowLayout is ok 
        buttonPanel.add(new JButton("OK"));
        buttonPanel.add(new JButton("Cancel"));

        // Let's create the drawing panel
        SelectGeometricFigures drawingPanel = new SelectGeometricFigures();
        Border blackline = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black);
        drawingPanel.setBorder(blackline);

        // Let's setup the frame, add our panels and show it 
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Select Shapes");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        f.getContentPane().add(drawingPanel); // to the center
        f.getContentPane().add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH); // and below
             
        f.setSize(500, 500);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

I got rid of the `null`-Layout. JFrame's content pane uses a BorderLayout by default, so I didn't create another JPanel. More information on laying out components can be found in the [Java tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html).

Edit: here's a down-scaled image of the JFrame shown by this example

[image: How it looks like]

Comment: It's still not painting on the panel though

Comment: If you run this code, you'll see a yellow circle in the upper left corner of the frame.

Comment: @Kevin, I've added an image how it should look if you run the example.